# Is there a way to use a ternary operator - or similar method - for picking the variable to assign to?

Tags: c#, .net, ternary-operator

is it possible to differ the variable I'm assigning to depending on a condition? The issue I came across is wanting to do this:

```
(bEquipAsSecondary ? currentWeaponOffhand : currentWeaponMainhand) = weaponToSwitchTo;
```

Instead of

```
if (bEquipAsSecondary)
{
    currentWeaponOffhand = weaponToSwitchTo;
}
else
{
    currentWeaponMainhand = weaponToSwitchTo;
}
```

Which results in the following error

> Error CS0131  The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

So I was wondering if there was a way to do this to cut down on space used and - in my opinion - make it look a bit neater?

Comment: What are the exact types of `currentWeaponOffhand` and `currentWeaponMainhand`?

Comment: These would be classes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use terinary operator for picking the variable to assign value to, you could make use of [ref locals/returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns).For example,

```
(bEquipAsSecondary ? ref currentWeaponOffhand : ref currentWeaponMainhand) = weaponToSwitchTo;
```

**Sample Output and Code**

```
var currentWeaponOffhand = 4;
var currentWeaponMainhand = 5;
var weaponToSwitchTo = 7;

(bEquipAsSecondary ? ref currentWeaponOffhand : ref currentWeaponMainhand) = weaponToSwitchTo;
Console.WriteLine($"When bEquipAsSecondary={bEquipAsSecondary},currentWeaponOffhand={currentWeaponOffhand},currentWeaponMainhand={currentWeaponMainhand}");
```

**Output**

```
When bEquipAsSecondary=False,currentWeaponOffhand=4,currentWeaponMainhand=7
When bEquipAsSecondary=True,currentWeaponOffhand=7,currentWeaponMainhand=5
```

Comment: Apparently, you don't need the `var _ = `

Comment: Nice one! Although would need to wait for unity to include C#7.2 to be able to use byref locals/returns

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if a ternary operator is a better choice than a regular `if-else` statement here. But you can use [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.7.2), something like this:

```
(bEquipAsSecondary ? new Action(() => currentWeaponOffhand = weaponToSwitchTo)
                   : () => currentWeaponMainhand = weaponToSwitchTo)();
```

Comment: I like this solution because it then generalizes into a framework for handling the effects of all game actions: you make an `Action` for every possible state mutation, and then the game logic figures out which `Action` from its collection needs to be executed, and executes it.

Answer (score 0):

The best / closest to what you're after that I could think of is this:

```
_ = condition ? (a = c) : (b = c);
```

### In context:

```
bool condition = true;
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;

_ = condition ? (a = c) : (b = c);
Console.WriteLine($"a = {a}; b = {b}; c = {c}");
```

### Outputs

```
a = 3; b = 2; c = 3
```

### Explanation

- `_ =` is required as the ternary operator is only available if we're assigning to something.  Here we use `_` as the "discard" variable; i.e. we don't care about the returned value; only that the operation itself occurs.
- use of brackets (e.g. `(a = c)` is required around the assignment since we need to return a result.  Performing `a = c` assigns the value of `c` to `a`, but doesn't return anything to the caller.  `(a = c)` on the other hand assigns `c` to `a` and then outputs the new value of `a`, making it available in the context of the rest of the method.  i.e. Aisde from the assignments this statement effectively reads `_ = condition ? c : c;`.

  - All else is as you'd expect from the standard ternary operator.  However, any questions, please say.

### Thoughts

It's not ideal as you have to specify each assignment separately; but does give you a form of shorthand...

I suspect this would generally be frowned upon in a code review though, since it's less readable than the standard if/else approach...

---

NB: In some other languages, a trick that could be used would be to have the condition act as an index for an array (e.g. false=0, true=1) and then exploit this in assigning the value...  However, whilst you can force this in C#, it's not pretty:

```
void Main()
{
    bool condition = true;  
    var a = new ReferenceType<int>(1);
    var b = new ReferenceType<int>(2);
    var c = new ReferenceType<int>(3);

    (new []{b, a})[ConvertBoolToInt(condition)].Value = c.Value;
    Console.WriteLine($"a = {a}; b = {b}; c = {c}");    
}
//in C# bools aren't natively convertable to int as they are in many langauges, so we'd need to provide a conversion method
public int ConvertBoolToInt(bool value)
{
    return value ? 1 : 0;
}
//to allow us to change the value rather than only the refenence, we'd need to wrap our data in something and update the value assigned to its property
public class ReferenceType<T>
{
    public T Value {get;set;}
    public ReferenceType(T intValue)
    {
        Value = intValue;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

That said, the above is talking about creating a more generic approach... If your use case is limited to weapon assignment / similar use cases, you could use a similar trick, such as this:

```
public enum WeaponHandEnum
{
    Primary //int = 0
    ,
    Secondary //int = 1
}
public class Player
{
    public Weapon[] Weapons {get;set;}
    public Player(Weapon primary = null, Weapon secondary = null)
    {
        Weapons = new Weapon[2] {primary, secondary}; 
    }
    public void Equip(WeaponHandEnum whichHand, Weapon newWeapon)
    {
        Weapons[(int)whichHand] = newWeapon;
    }
}
public class Weapon{ /* ... */ }
```

---

If you find you're having to do a lot of statements like this throughout your code and want a way to keep your line count down, you're best of with something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    bool condition = true;  
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var c = 3;
    SomeKindaHelper.TernaryAssign<int>(condition, ref a, ref b, c);
    Console.WriteLine($"a = {a}; b = {b}; c = {c}");    
}
public static class SomeKindaHelper
{
    public static void TernaryAssign<T>(bool condition, ref T assignToMeIfConditionIsTrue, ref T assignToMeIfConditionIsFalse, T newValue)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            assignToMeIfConditionIsTrue = newValue;
        }
        else 
        {
            assignToMeIfConditionIsFalse = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

i.e. Whilst this is several lines of code to define the helper method, you can reuse it all over the place as a one liner, and it's much more readable, if not so clever.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer !

Comment: No worries / good luck.  Obviously Anu's solution's better for the pure ternary approach (I'd tried that but was in PS mode so used `[ref]` instead of `ref` and concluded it didn't work; doh!).  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator to choose an *action* that will update the right slot.

```
//Define action to equip appropriate slot
var equipAction = bEquipAsSecondary
    ? new Action<Weapon>( w => currentWeaponOffhand = w )
    : new Action<Weapon>( w => currentWeaponMainhand = w );

//Now equip the weapon
equipAction(weaponToSwitchTo);
```