# Inline if statement inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, foreach, syntax

Is there any way you can do something like this without using the usual If syntax?

```
foreach (var cell in ws.Cells[header_row, 1, header_row, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
{
    cell.Address == "SomeValue" ? break : continue;
}
```

Visual Studio doesn't seem to allow an inline If statement with this kind of results.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it actually not possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know C#, but in most languages, an "inline if" (a ternary/conditional expression) doesn't allow statements. Ternarys are not simply a shorter version of an `if`. They're meant to evaluate to one of two values, and `continue` and `break` don't evaluate to anything.

Comment: turnary *operator* must return a *value* (or throw exception); neither `break` nor `continue` are *value*s

Comment: When using the conditional operator you have to use either expressions or you can throw an exception.  You cannot use control commands like break and continue.  The operator isn't just short for an `if-else`.  It's short for an `if-else` where both are assigning a value to the same variable.

Comment: Not sure whether this solution works in your case or not, you might want to give it a try though https://stackoverflow.com/a/53362143/2946329

Comment: As other's have already noted you don't even need the `continue` since that's the default behavior when you reach the end of a loop.  Note that you cannot have this break or continue logic in the middle of a loop as that would make the rest of the code that comes after it in the loop unreachable.

Comment: in both cases here, you are - one way or another - just going to execute part or all of the loop; but ... those are both idempotent (usually). So: what is it you are actually trying to do? are you trying to test whether *any* element meets the condition? if so: you might be looking for `bool isAny = ws.Cells[header_row, 1, header_row, ws.Dimension.End.Column].Any(cell => cell.Address == "SomeValue");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(cell.Address == "SomeValue") break;
```

In your sample code, continue isn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ's [`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netframework-4.8) to obtain the desired behaviour:

```
foreach (var cell in ws.Cells[header_row, 1, header_row, ws.Dimension.End.Column].TakeWhile(x => x.Address != "SomeValue"))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What your are doing with the `?` isn't an inline if-statement, this *operator* is called the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) (it's sometimes also called the ternary operator, but don't confuse it with the [elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator)).

As you can read from the Microsoft documentation, you don't use it to control flow of your application, but as a shorthand to conditionally assign something. As such, the ternary operator must either return a value or throw an exception.

Rewrite your code as such:

```cs
if (cell.Address == "SomeValue")
    break;
```

Notice how I omitted the [`continue;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue) statement, as it is not needed in your case, as the continue statement jumps to the next iteration without completing this iteration (which I assume you don't want here)

Here is a short example of how to use the ternary:

```cs
// Instead of this:
if (foo)
    bar = "Foo";
else
    bar = "Not Foo";

// You can write this
bar = foo ? "Foo" : "Not Foo";
```

Comment: FYI it's official name is the conditional operator.  Ternary refers to the fact that it's the only operator that takes 3 operands.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you're absolutely correct, did some further reading into the elvis operator and turns out that while syntactically similar they're quite different. I update my answer to respect it